# Handling large JS file with lots of global functions in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

A legacy project I am working on currently has a file with 100s of functions defined in the global scope, dependant on JQuery (4k+ LOC). A problem the team is facing is having to deal with IE11 as a large majority of clients are still using it. The new team would also like to have to not worry about this and for now, we have set-up webpack to handle new functionality. We would also like to apply this to the older scripts without having to re-write everything.

I am aware that the intention of webpack is to modularize JS for the front end but I am also curious to know if we are out of luck with the legacy code or if we can do something to handle it and progress to a workflow that is more suited to modern JS.

An example of a file may look like:

```
const global = { ... }

function f1() { ... }

var doSomethingElse = true;
function doSomething(param) { ... }

function helloWorld() { ... }
...
```

Our current approach to new functionality is to define modules of shared functionality, importing them and using them where required but also keeping to the one JS file per page model as that is what we identified as the best strategy without having to re-write everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply attach the functions and variables to the `window` object to make them global. So

```
const global = { ... }
window.global = global;

function f1() { ... }
window.f1 = f1;

var doSomethingElse = true;
window.doSomethingElse = doSomethingElse;
//...
```

Comment: I like this approach in the interim before we dedicate resources to refactoring completely.  Thanks.